# How to get CRTSCTS defined in termios.h?

Tags: c, ubuntu-18.04, termios, flow-control

My machine has `CRTSCTS` #defined inside a `#ifdef __USE_MISC` which stops it being available to C programs which I compile.

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/termios.h:

```
...       
#define  B4000000 0010017
#define __MAX_BAUD B4000000
#ifdef __USE_MISC
# define CIBAUD   002003600000      /* input baud rate (not used) */
# define CMSPAR   010000000000      /* mark or space (stick) parity */
# define CRTSCTS  020000000000      /* flow control */
#endif

/* c_lflag bits */
#define ISIG    0000001
#define ICANON  0000002
...
```

How do I get access to CRTSCTS without just hacking the value `020000000000` into my program?

I already `#include <termios.h>` and many other headers.

I am also using:

```
#define __USE_POSIX199309
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
#include <time.h>    /* nanosleep needs lines above */
```

Comment: `#define __USE_POSIX199309` From `man feature_test_macros`: `These macros have names prefixed by two
       underscores (e.g., __USE_MISC).  Programs should never define these
       macros directly`

Comment: KamilCuk is right - what are you trying to accomplish with `__USE_POSIX199309` ?

Comment: Using __USE_POSIX199309 and similar will have no effect. They are undefined in "features.h" and then built. The process trys to determine your platform and choose defines that are appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The `__USE_MISC` macro is an internal definition that, though I suppose you could define this yourself, it's better to find the proper feature-test macro that enables it.

On my CentOS 7 system, `/usr/include/features.h` has a whole range of these kinds of macros, and it appears that `__USE_MISC` is enabled by `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_SVID_SOURCE`; it's not clear which one is compatible with other things you're going to need.

```
... // features.h
#if defined _BSD_SOURCE || defined _SVID_SOURCE
# define __USE_MISC     1
#endif
```

Try `#define _BSD_SOURCE` at the top of your program - before all the includes - and see how it goes.

Ref: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above , to enable __USE_MISC macro you can define __DEFAULT_SOURCE macro because I tried with defining _BSD_SOURCE but got this warning

> ***warning**: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]*

I managed it this way.